# $f$ is an entire function with Im $f\geq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is an entire function with $\operatorname{Im}f \geq 0$. Then which of the followings are true:

1. $f$ is constant.
2. $\operatorname{Re}f$ is constant.
3. $f = 0$.
4. $f'$ is a non-zero constant.

That (3) & (4) are wrong can be shown by using $f(z) = i$. But I'm clueless about the remaining two options.

Comment: Would you be able to answer the question if we changed it to "$f$ is entire with its image lying in the unit disk?"

Comment: Entire functions restricted "so much" usually want to be *constants*. Note also that 1)$\Rightarrow$2).

Comment: I think I've got the point. Non-constant entire function comes arbitrarily close to each complex number. Then both 1 & 2 must be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g=\dfrac{1}{f+i}$(thanks to point out my mistake), then $g$ is entire and $|g|<1$, now you can conclude that $g$ is a constant with the Liouville's theorem(I forget it's name). Consequently $f$ is also a constant.
Also by Picard's theorem, that the range of any nonconstant entire function must contain the complex except for at most one point.

Comment: You rather mean $g=1/(f+i)$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hints:**
(1) If $f$ is entire then so is $e^{if}$
(2) $|e^{if}|=e^{-\operatorname{Im}(f)}\leq 1$
(3) Use [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29)

Comment: why is $|e^{if}|=e^{-\text{Im(f)}}$?

Comment: Just to help somebody who can't figure out why $|e^{if}| = e^{- \Im (f)}$, assuming $f = u+iv$:

$|e^{if}| = |e^{i (u+iv)}| = |e^{-v}| | \cos u + i \sin u| = |e^{-v}|$

Answer (score 2):

Such a function $f$ would map the entire plane into the upper half-plane.  The Picard theorem says this is impossible, since an entire nonconstant function must map the plane onto itself or onto the complex plane punctured by a "missing" point.  The mapping $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the conformal map $F:\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$

$$
F:z\mapsto \frac{i-z}{i+z}.
$$
We can write
$$
g := F\circ f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}.
$$
Then $g$ is entire and bounded by $1$, so it is constant. Hence, $f$ is constant as well.